# How do I convert this post-checkout hook to be usable with pre-commit?

Tags: pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have a post-checkout hook that I'm trying to convert to be usable with pre-commit.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# 0 means 'git checkout somefile' (don't do anything)
# 1 means 'git checkout branchname'

echo "> $*"
(($3)) || exit 0

declare -a blocked
blocked+=('master' 'main' 'examples')
printf -v blocked_rx '%s|' "${blocked[@]}"
blocked_rx="${blocked_rx%?}"

# shellcheck disable=SC2034
read -r prev cur < <(git reflog | awk 'NR==1{ print $6 " " $8; exit }')

[[ $cur =~ $blocked_rx ]] \
  && echo "WARNING: You cannot push $cur branch to remote!"

exit 0
```

I've created a `.pre-commit-hooks.yaml` file.

```yaml
- id: warn-branch-on-checkout
  name: Message to stderr if branch
  language: script
  pass_filenames: false
  always_run: true
  stages: [post-checkout]
  entry: pre-commit-hooks/warn-branch-on-checkout
```

And my `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file looks like:

```yaml
default_install_hook_types:
  - pre-commit
  - post-checkout

repos:
  - repo: https://MyCompany@dev.azure.com/MyCompany/MyProject/_git/myrepo
    rev: v0.1.12
    hooks:
      - id: warn-branch-on-checkout
        args: ['examples']
```

The bash script lives in `pre-commit-hooks` off the top level of the repository.

As far as I can tell, pre-commit is not calling `warn-branch-on-checkout` (I added the `echo "> $*"` in the script).

`pre-commit.log` in the cache dir is not being created.

What am I doing wrong?

Added examples of run:

```bash
$ git checkout examples
Switched to branch 'examples'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/examples'.
HERE: /home/harleypig/projects/guardrail/.git/hooks
1: /usr/bin/python3 -mpre_commit hook-impl --config=.pre-commit-config.yaml --hook-type=post-checkout --hook-dir /home/harleypig/projects/guardrail/.git/hooks -- 79d1096b98caa40e672a502855cb139d72de2ada 79d1096b98caa40e672a502855cb139d72de2ada 1
Message to stderr if branch..............................................Passed
```

I added a couple of echo statements to the pre-commit generated hook (the `HERE:` and `1:` lines above).

I don't see `> blah blah blah` so the script isn't being called at all.

Comment: show the command(s) you ran and the full output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for adding the output

pre-commit [hides the output by default unless there is a failure](https://pre-commit.com/#config-verbose) -- this is to keep your output clean and noise free (noisy outputs tend to get ignored)

you can change this to always display output by setting the `verbose: true` option (or by exiting nonzero -- which doesn't affect `post-checkout` since it is too late to affect "success").  note that `verbose: true` is intended mainly as a debugging mechanism so generally adding noise to the output is discouraged

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: Thank you. That got me past this issue.